# Error with displaying image in java. AWT-EventQueue-0 error

Tags: java

When executing my code, there is an error problem with this code:

```
ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String path = "";
                String extension = "";

                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

                    path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();

                    int i = path.lastIndexOf('.');
                    if (i >= 0) {
                        extension = path.substring(i+1);
                    }
                }

                try {

                    if (extension.equals("ppm")) {

                        Paint.imgs.add(new ppm(path));

                img.setImage(resize(Paint.imgs.get(Integer.parseInt(path)).img, 544, 372));
                img.repaint();

                    }

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }

        });
```

especially with the line`img.setImage(resize(Paint.imgs.get(Integer.parseInt(path)).img, 544, 372));`

It looks like the path to image is correct, so I don't know why it does not work.
The output is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C:\Users\ciola\Desktop\pb.ppm"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at paint.binar$1.actionPerformed(binar.java:435)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    ...
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: It's wrong that you are calling Integer.parseInt on your path. That's definitely wrong

Comment: @ControlAltDel, then, it does not work. Red underlined.

Comment: That's because you are trying to reference something in an array. I don't know how you expect to go from a file path to a number index

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the logic of your code.  As written it does this:

- get the absolute pathname for a file
- find the extension
- if the extension is "ppm":

  - load the image into your cache (I'm guessing that is what `Paint.imgs.add(new ppm(path))` is intended to do.
  - fetch the image from the cache using `path` as the index.

But here's the problem.  **The `path` is not an index.**  It is the absolute pathname.  It is the *full* pathname with the directory part and the filename part ... complete with the extension.  You can't parse *that* as an integer.

Solution: unclear - it depends on what your strategy for caching is, and how the images are actually identified.

- If the pathnames actually do contain a unique number that corresponds to your caches indexing scheme, then modify `get(Integer.parseInt(path))` to extract the unique number from `path` before parsing.
- If not, then you need to do the image cache lookup some other way.

---

Advice: to avoid problems like this, have a clear mental model of how your code is actually supposed to work.

> @ControlAltDel, then, it does not work. Red underlined.

This strongly suggests that you got where you are by trying some change to *make the compilation error go away*.  That approach sometimes works: sometimes, you get lucky!  But often it results in a program that *doesn't make sense* ... and gives runtime errors when you attempt to run it.

A better idea is to understand what the compiler is telling you, and then understand the real nature of your mistake.  The compiler (or your IDE) doesn't understand what you are trying to do.  Its "suggestions" are just that.  It depends on you to make a *rational* decision when choosing which (if any) to accept.